# Google Chrome and Firefox and "ask where to download" option failing

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, 22.04

If I enable the option:

- "Ask where to save each file before downloading" in Google Chrome, **Chrome is frozen after download**.
- "Always ask you where to save files" in Firefox, **it does not start downloading at all**.

I think that maybe it's a problem using the native ubuntu window to select the folder, but no idea how to fix it or if it's a bug in Ubuntu 22.04

```
~$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 102.0.5005.115

~$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 101.0.1

~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Tested with kernel 5.17.0-1011-oem and 5.15

Comment: it is a bug with gtk4 iirc, and there are at least 2-3 questions here about it already

Comment: Thanks @Esther. Do you have links to these questions? I can not find it. Maybe we can flag it as duplicate.